# No PUT method in DRF using ModelViewset

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using Django 2.2 with Django Rest Framework 3.7. 
I have a class like this:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

I've created UserSerializer like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'name', 'password')
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            name=validated_data['name'],
        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        print('lalala from serialzier')
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()

        instance.username = validated_data['username']
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Only allowed methods being shown are - Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS

I wonder why I am unable to perform actions like PUT, DELETE, RETRIEVE. These are by default supported by using ModelViewset as per documentation.

In shown code neither serializer's update() nor views.py update() method getting called. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question?

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def put(self, request, id, format=None):
        ...

    def delete(self, request, id, format=None):
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks, if I use put in views and hit 

```request : http://localhost:8000/api/user/1
output : Not Found: /api/user/1
```
If I modify my request -
```request : http://localhost:8000/api/user
output : api found and goes inside function.
```
But problem is that this is not how PUT APIs work, it must get object id in url and should be able to modify that object. Also, even later approach do not give url error but request.data, args, kwargs all are empty while I am sending json data in body via POSTMAN. So overall, it does not work.

Comment: Matching with http://localhost:8000/api/user/<id> now.
The previous version was waiting for an id in the json : `PUT http://localhost:8000/api/user/` with `{ "id":1, ... }` for example.

Comment: I have chanegd my code to not to use ViewSet and using APIView and issue is resolved now. I do not know why it behaved so with ViewSet. Thanks for your help.